# If zeroes of the equation of DE are $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=\pm i$ then how to know the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given DE: $$x'''-x''+x'-x=e^t~.$$ First we find a solution to homogeneous DE rewritten as equation: $\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\lambda-1=0 \; \lambda_1=1 \; \lambda_{2,3}=\pm i \Rightarrow x_h=C_1e^t+C_2\cos t +C_3\sin t$.

It is said that particular solution is $Ate^t ( \text{ because } \alpha =1)$.

I don't understand why such particular solution?

Could we take any one of those three components in general solution and substitute $C$ with $A$ and that would give us the right particular solution or is there some other reasoning as to how to find a particular solution if general solution is given?

Comment: $Ae^t$ for a constant $A$ clearly is not a particular solution; it only satisfies the homogeneous equation

Comment: That particular solution is not correct; adding that to a solution to the homogeneous equation makes a solution to the homogeneous equation again. The usual way to correctly guess the particular solution here is $Ate^t$ where A is to be determined.

Comment: @Ian You are right, it's $Ate^t$

Comment: @Ian going through the tutorial, I still don't understand why it's $Ate^t$ instead of $Ae^t$ as in cases where $g(t)=e^t$ the guess is given as $Ae^t$

Comment: $Ae^t$ is already a solution to the homogeneous equation, so it can't give a nontrivial solution to the inhomogeneous equation. In this case, the standard trick is to multiply by $t$ and try again.

Comment: @Wizact Ok, thank you, this was the most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular solution should be since$e^t$ is already part of the homogeneous solution:
$$x_p(t)=Ate^t$$
You can also try this:
$$x'''-x''+x'-x=e^t$$
$$e^{⁻t}(x'''-x'')+e^{⁻t}(x'-x)=1$$
$$(x''e^{⁻t})'+(xe^{⁻t})'=1$$
$$x''e^{⁻t}+xe^{⁻t}=c_1+t$$
$$x''+x=(c_1+t)e^{t}$$
$$R^2+1=0 \implies R=\pm i$$
$$x(t)=C\cos(t)+D\sin(t)$$
And the particular solution is now :
$$x_p(t)=(A+Bt)e^t$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x'''-x''+x'-x=e^t$$
$$\implies (D^3-D^2+D-1)x=e^t$$where $~~D\equiv \dfrac{d}{dt}~$.

Roots of the auxiliary equation are  $~1,~~i,~~-i~$.

Here $~~f(D)=D^3-D^2+D-1~$.

Clearly $~f(1)=0~$, but $~f'(1)=2\ne 0~$

For **particular integral** (P.I.),

$\text{P.I.  =}~~\dfrac{1}{D^3-D^2+D-1}~~e^t$

$~~~~~~=~t~\dfrac{1}{2}~~e^t~~~~~$ (by rule $2$)

$~~~~~~=~~\dfrac{1}{2}~t~e^t~~~~~~$

---

> Consider a differential equation of the form $f(D)y=X$
>
> If $X=e^{ax}$, then
>
> $1.$ P.I.$\quad = \frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{f(a)}$, if $f(a)\neq 0$
>
> $2.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=x~\frac{e^{ax}}{f'(a)}$, if $~f(a)=0~$but$~f'(a)\ne 0$
>
> $3.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=x^2~\frac{e^{ax}}{f''(a)}$, if $~f(a)=0,~f'(a)= 0~$but$~f''(a)\ne 0$
>
> and so on.